# Select rows no more than 6 months old using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following query and I want to select all the videos from the table which are no more than 6 months older than the current time of the selected video `:time`

I got this value `15638400` from this: `echo strtotime('+6 month', 0);`

All the times in the table are in the `UNIX timestamp` format.

When I run this query all the videos get selected as this line was not there. So I mean the results do depends on `having time - :time < 15638400`. If I remove this the result is the same.

A video will be selected and it will have a timestamp of X for ex. Than this query will return all the videos that are uploaded 6 moths or sooner in comparison with the first video. So 6 months or less than the value X.

```
$query = "select `video_name`, `title`, `yt_id` from `videos`
    where match(`genre`) against (+:genre IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    and match(`country`) against (+:country IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    having time - :time < 15638400
    and `video_name` != :video_name  ORDER BY RAND() limit :limit";

try {
    $run_query = $db->prepare($query);

    $run_query->bindValue(':country', $this->country);
    $run_query->bindValue(':genre', $this->genre);
    $run_query->bindValue(':time', $this->time);
    $run_query->bindValue(':video_name', $this->video_name);
    $run_query->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $run_query->execute();

    return $run_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
select id
from your_table
where your_timestamp_column <= (now() - interval 6 month);
```

Comment: I want to compare it with the time of a particular video, `:time` variable not with `now()`

Comment: now() is for the current timestamp, you need to replace your_timestamp_column with :time variable (column)

Comment: I think you didn't  understood me right. A video will be selected and it will have a timestamp of X for ex. Than this query will return all the videos that are uploaded 6 moths or sooner in comparison with the first video. So 6 months or less than the value X.